Code distance and existence of isometry in tensor networks
Recently, I've been looking into quantum error correction codes as tensor networks. I collected the following "facts" (which may be wrong, if so, please feel free to correct me on them).
A $[[n, k, d]]$ code can recover any $t = (d-1)/2$ errors or, equivalently, any $d-1$ erasure errors. This is equivalent to there being an isometry from the erased qubits plus the logical ones to the remaining qubits according to Farrelly et al.
Can this be used to "easily" determine the code distance $d$ of a code obtained by contraction of multiple individual codes? Specifically, if I take a bunch of perfect tensors (i.e. $[[5, 1, 3]]$ codes) as nodes in a tensor network and contract some of their legs to obtain a new code, can I find its distance from how many physical logical legs at most the network can be seen as an isometry to the remaining legs? This would mean I could find the number of correctable erasure errors $d-1$ and thus the code distance.
Here's a visualization of what I mean. Each of the nodes is a $[[5, 1, 3]]$ code, the logical leg pointing out of the screen and the physical legs ordered counterclockwise. Because these are perfect tensors, grouping up to two physical legs together with the logical leg as "input legs" and the rest as "output" legs will result in an isometry. Based on this reasoning, I would claim that the code given by the network in the drawing is a $[[9, 3, 3]]$ code. In the case of two erasure errors, I illustrated which legs can be viewed as input and output of each node as an isometry. Then, the full network just concatenates isometries and is thus an isometry itself.

Does this method work? Is it true that we can find $d$ by finding the maximal number of arbitrary physical legs which can be grouped with the logical legs to get an isometry?

This looks reasonable to me at first glance. For the "holographic" code, also built with the $[[5,1,3]]$ code and tensor contraction, you get a series of $[[n,k,3]]$ codes as you add more "layers". I think the process is related to (maybe the same as) fusion applied along the edges between nodes
